# How to execute "an exe with return value" in java?

Tags: java, c++, exe

I created an executable using cpp which accepts two integer values and then returns the sum. I'm executing the EXE with Java using the following code:

```
try {
    pr = rt.exec("C:\\Users\\babesha.fm\\Desktop\\SUM.exe 10 5");
    int exitVal = pr.waitFor();

    System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used the return statement while creating the exe.
But the problem is when I executed this exe by using the above java code. pr.waitFor(); statement returns the sum value instead of successful exicution.Did I done anything wrong .

Comment: "I got the exit value as the sum value." That's what I'd expect. What do you mean by "call the exe with return value"? What do you want to achieve that you're not already achieving? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I was confused by that sentence as well. I'm guessing the questioner want to make a recursive call using the return value in order to reuse this block of code? @BabeshaFM please clarify.

Comment: I would suggest to rename the question to "How to execute external process from Java code and get the error number".

Comment: No..My exe accept two numbers and return the sum of these two numbers. The exe is created in cpp and the sum is printed as return sum.when I execute the java code I got the value of Process.waitfor as the output of the EXE instead of zero.Is there any other method to get the exit value as zero instead of sum.

Comment: You need to read the processes `InputStream`...

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xxx.EXE p1 p2");
// This is as same as what we do at DOS Prompt.
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
int n = 0;
while(n != -1)
{
n = is.read();
System.out.print(n);
}
```

Comment: Thnks for your reply.Actually my doubt is while executing this code    int exitVal = process.waitFor();My code returns the output of the exe  instead of zero[ie,Sucessful execution]